# Removing libcurl3 on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, git, libcurl

Recently my git started not to work and when I checked the reason, it appears that it's related with libcurl3-gnutls and it's suggested to downgrade it. When I try to install a previous version, the installer naturally complains about having already a later version in the system. Therefore, I decided to remove the previous version first by using `sudo apt-get remove libcurl3-gnutls` However, I get a warning which makes me think twice;

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  git-man liberror-perl ocl-icd-libopencl1
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apt-transport-https brasero brasero-cdrkit evolution-data-server
  gir1.2-gdata-0.0 gir1.2-totem-1.0 gir1.2-totem-plparser-1.0 git
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad kdepim-runtime
  kerneloops-daemon libbrasero-media3-1 libcmis-0.4-4 libcurl3-gnutls
  libgdata13 libgrilo-0.2-1 libkolab0 libkolabxml1 liboauth0 libquvi7
  libraptor2-0 librasqal3 librdf0 libreoffice-base-core
  libreoffice-base-drivers libreoffice-calc libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw
  libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-impress
  libreoffice-math libreoffice-ogltrans libreoffice-pdfimport
  libreoffice-presentation-minimizer libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb
  libreoffice-writer libslv2-9 libtotem-plparser18 libtotem0
  mint-meta-cinnamon mint-meta-codecs mint-meta-core mintsources python-pycurl
  python3-pycurl python3-uno thin-client-config-agent totem totem-mozilla
  totem-plugins totem-plugins-extra transmission-gtk
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  mintsources python-pycurl (due to mintsources)
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 55 to remove and 53 not upgraded.
After this operation, 297 MB disk space will be freed.
You are about to do something potentially harmful.
To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'
```

Any recommendation on how to proceed ?

Comment: Can you try and upgrade it instead of un-installing it? (http://serverfault.com/a/580997/783)

Comment: Seems like it worked =)

Comment: first try to get rid of unnecessary packages by issuing the commands `sudo apt-get autoremove` and then try to install once again

Comment: I remember trying that but result was the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As recommended in "[How do I force my Debian system to update GnuTLS?](https://serverfault.com/a/580997/783)", one way would be to:

- not un-install
- upgrade instead

That is:

```
apt-get update; apt-cache policy libgnutls26
apt-get update; apt-cache policy libgnutls27
```